# How to get rid of the unwanted commas

Tags: ruby

I am trying to display which moderators are currently in the room. This is what I did:

```
puts m.roster.keys.map { |v| "Mods in the room are: #{if m.roster[v].x[0].role.to_s.include?('moderator') then v end}" }.join(", ")
```

The result is:

```
Mods in the room are: , , User3, User4, , , , , , , User11, , User13
```

Are there any ways to get rid of those unwanted commas but retain commas that separate each like the following?

```
Mods in the room are: User3, User4, User11, User 13
```

Comment: Are you sure `"Mods in the room are:"` is printed only once with your code?

Comment: What is `m`? What is `roster`?

Comment: I'm guessing you could call `.compact.join(', ')` to remove nil elements from the array but this code is so terse that its hard to know what your intent is.

Comment: m.roster shows the roles of each person in the room, but m.roster is correct. @sawa

Comment: It's still shows ``Mods in the room are: , , User3, User4, , , , , , , User11, , User13``, @max

Comment: Oh, it's actually prints out a lot of "Mods in the room are:" @sawa

Comment: ``["User1", "User2", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "User11", "", "", "User14", ""]``

How do I get rid of the ``""``?

Comment: What is the logic that decides when to insert a space in the item? Do all strings start with `User`, and is that the only place you want to put a space after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
puts "Mods in the room are: #{m.roster.select {|k,v| v.x[0].role.to_s.include?('moderator') }.keys.join(", ")}"
```

I believe that will give you the list of moderators.

Comment: Great! That was it! Thanks so much!

Comment: @MarryJane This does not insert a space after `User` (when it is followed by `13`), as you wanted.

Comment: @sawa, I believe that the space that you mention was a typo in the example.  The original code did not attempt to modify usernames to insert spaces, only build a list and separate them with ", " for output.  The usernames "User1", "User2", "User11", etc are simply representative placeholders for the usernames, while not being the actual usernames.

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow your code, but you can modify your erroneous result as follows.

```
str = "Mods in the room are: , , User3, User4, , , , , , , User11, , User13"

first, *rest = str.split /(?:\s*,+)+/
  #=> ["Mods in the room are:", " User3", " User4", " User11", " User13"] 
"%s %s" % [first, rest.join(', ').lstrip]
  #=> "Mods in the room are: User3,  User4,  User11,  User13"
```